# how to set associate a hotkey to my chrome extension browser_action?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have set up a hotkey in my manifest.json file, and a bogus listener in my background.js

If i hit the hotkey combination, it works.

Now, i'm missing how to actually do what i want it to do: launch the extension's browser_action : open the popup.html (which is a search your bookmarks input field).
I've been looking for a method like `chrome.trigger('browserAction');` Perhaps i'm missing something really obvious...

my background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  alert('Command:'+ command);
});
```

manifest.json (extract)

```
  "commands": {
    "browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
        "mac": "Alt+Shift+U"
      },
      "description": "Opens the extension"
    }
  },
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "YURLS",
      "default_icon": "icon16.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

ah. Simply changing the command name to the magic word `_execute_browser_action` in the manifest.json file did the trick.

```
"commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+U",
        "mac": "Alt+Shift+U"
      },
      "description": "Opens Yurl"
    }
  }
```